# How to set inverval in milisecond between gif frames with Imagemagick++

Tags: c++, qt, imagemagick

Creating a Gif using ImageMagick 6.9.7.4.

I convert a vector of `QImage`, to `ImageMagick`  image type and create a gif using the static method. But resulted gif is so fast, how can set I an interval between frames, or make by gif some slow?

```
std::vector<Magick::Image> listOfImages;
for (QImage &image:m_listOfImages)
{
    qDebug()<< image.size();
    {
        listOfImages.push_back(QImageToImage(image));
    }
}
qDebug()<< listOfImages.size();
QString gifName=QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString(QStringLiteral("hh-mm-ss"))+".gif";
Magick::writeImages(listOfImages.begin(), listOfImages.end(), gifName.toStdString());
qDebug()<< "Done";
```

and `QImage` to `Magick::Image`

```
Magick::Image DspPresenter::QImageToImage(QImage &qimage)
{
    qDebug() << "toImage:" << qimage.width() << qimage.height();

    const Magick::Geometry geometry(qimage.width(), qimage.height());
    const Magick::ColorRGB color(0.5, 0.2, 0.3);
    Magick::Image newImage(geometry, color);
    double scale = 1 / 256.0;
    newImage.modifyImage();
    Magick::PixelPacket  *pixels;
    Magick::ColorRGB mgc;
    for (int y = 0; y < qimage.height(); ++y)
    {
        pixels = newImage.setPixels(0, y, newImage.columns(), 1);
        for (int x = 0; x < qimage.width(); ++x)
        {
            QColor pix = qimage.pixel(x, y);
            mgc.red(scale *pix.red());
            mgc.green(scale *pix.green());
            mgc.blue(scale *pix.blue());
            *pixels++ = mgc;
        }
        newImage.syncPixels();
    }
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Image img1( "100x100", "white" );
img1.pixelColor( 49, 49, "red" );
frames.push_back(img1);

Image img2( "100x100", "red" );
img2.pixelColor( 49, 49, "white" );
frames.push_back(img2);

img1.animationDelay(2000);
img2.animationDelay(2000);*/

Magick::writeImages(frames.begin(), frames.end(), "f:\\2.gif");
```

Sure, you should set an `animationDelay` property in `Magick::Image`  object